# Is this the right way to install Jasmine on CircleCi platform (Ubuntu 14.04) ?

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, circleci

I have already tried the code provided in here: 
https://inviqa.com/blog/testing-javascript-get-started-jasmine-0
It just doesn't see that bower is installed.

I have tried this and it worked out:

```
npm install -g jasmine //global installation
jasmine init
```

It seems just about right.

I want to install it via composer because that's how we install the PhpUnit. I am not sure where to look at. 
How to install correctly jasmine on ubuntu trusty 14.04 (circleCi) ? Am I doing it correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be official Composer instructions. NPM and Gem installs are available via the official website: https://jasmine.github.io/pages/getting_started.html

A GitHub Gist shows an example of creating a composer install: https://gist.github.com/sampart/6294354 . That uses the standalone build.

Comment: I have looked at those tricks and I have tried both of them. 
But I have find the solution and it's really extremely easy. 
All I wanted to do is to call the jasmine from my command line which is really easy.